# how to fix theme.spacing.unit warning in material-ui-dropzone?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use material-ui-dropzone like this:

```
//App.js
<Dropzone/>
```

but this error occurred in the console:

```
 index.js:1375 Warning: Material-UI: theme.spacing.unit usage has been deprecated. It will be removed in v5. You can replace `theme.spacing.unit * y` with `theme.spacing(y)`.
```

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: You can't fix it, it's an issue with the library using theme.spacing.unit which is deprecated. https://github.com/Yuvaleros/material-ui-dropzone/issues/53 . You will have to wait for the library maintainers to fix it

Answer (score 5):

Frist:
find your code "theme.spacing.unit"; 
Second:
for example : "theme.spacing.unit * 4" ,  Please change it to "theme.spacing(4)".

Answer (score 5):

Here is the full documentation on v3 to v4 transition and using spacing units.

Link: [theme-spacing-v4](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-codemod/README.md#theme-spacing-api%60)

Here are the most frequent examples regarding spacing unit:

**Basic spacing unit**

v3 `theme.spacing.unit`

v4 `theme.spacing(1)`

**Reducing spacing**

v3 `theme.spacing.unit / 5`

v4 `theme.spacing(1/5)`

**Extending spacing**

v3 `theme.spacing.unit * 5`

v4 `theme.spacing(5)`